# MongoDB with c# Making sure records are locked while working on them

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi i am using mongodb as my database. My question is how can i make sure that when i do a query for one document or lots of documents. Example:

```
mongo.GetCollection("orders").Find(Query.EQ("OrderStatus", "unshiped")).ToList();
```

How to make sure that the documents that are in this list are locked and nobody can edit them and what ever i do in the code with this records when i loop them true and then save them it should unlock it

Answer (score 0):

> MongoDB supports atomic operations on single documents.  MongoDB does
>   not support traditional locking and complex transactions for a number
>   of reasons:
>
> - First, in sharded environments, distributed locks could be expensive and slow.  Mongo DB's goal is to be lightweight and fast.
> - We dislike the concept of deadlocks.  We want the system to be simple    and predictable without these sort of surprises.
> - We want Mongo DB to work well for realtime problems.  If an operation may execute which locks large amounts of data, it might stop
>     some small light queries for an extended period of time.

I think your best bet is adding a `locked` property to your documents, and to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the isLocked field in collection. Before update you can lock and unlock to finish the work. If you want more spesific lock mechanism, Add Guid in LockedId field.